# Android studio - empty activity won't sync - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest

Tags: android, gradle, httprequest

I get the same error trying to compile sample code from github. It's a new installation of Android studio Iguana 2023.2.1.

compileSdk = 34
minSdk = 24

I tried "Invalidate caches" and restarted Android Studio. As far as I understand HttpRequest has been deprecated for a long time so I don't understand why it's looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by uninstalling Android Studio, deleting appropriate directories under AppData, and reinstalling.